# Merging Pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

So, I have two pandas dataframes:

```
a       b
abc    def
ghi    jkl
mno    pqr
```

and

```
a       b
abc    def
ghi    jkl
stu    vwx
```

What I want to do is merge these dataframes but keep only the ones that are non-overlapping (row 3 in data frame 1 and 2)

```
a     b
stu   vwx
mno   pqr
```

Comment: Think about editing your question with slightly more meaningful data (e.g. `col A`, `col B`, `A1`, `B1`, etc.) as it will make it easier to follow what you mean. Also tell us what you have tried already, share some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with outer join and parameter `indicator`, then filter rows where not value `both` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last remove column `_merge` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for default `index` (0,1,2...):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
print (df)
     a    b      _merge
0  abc  def        both
1  ghi  jkl        both
2  mno  pqr   left_only
3  stu  vwx  right_only

df = df[df._merge != 'both'].drop('_merge', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     a    b
0  mno  pqr
1  stu  vwx
```